# Are Java annotations serializable?

Tags: java, serialization, annotations

The Java [Annotation interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/Annotation.html) does not extend `Serializable`. However, Java annotation values are serializable (implemented using `java.lang.reflect.Proxy`, with a serializable invocation handler).

Is this guaranteed anywhere? My search-foo is failing to find a reference. Or if I need to serialize annotation instances safely, do I need to create my own serialization proxies?

Comment: My intuition is yes, since they're static. Do they even need to be `Serializable` because of that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Annotation objects returned by methods of `java.lang.reflect.AnnotatedElement` are `Serializable`. This is what [API says](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/AnnotatedElement.html): *This interface allows annotations to be read reflectively. All annotations returned by methods in this interface are immutable and serializable*.

All classes capable of returning annotation objects (Class, Constructor, Field, Method, Package, Parameter) implement AnnotatedElement and are obliged to create / return Serializable objects by the above contract.

Answer (score 10):

Annotations are part of the class definition, and thus would never be written to a serialization stream (at least not with standard java serialization) when serializing an instance of a class which has annotations.

UPDATE:
I guess i missed the point of the original question which was referring to specifically serializing an instance of an actual Annotation.

Comment: I am specifically asking about annotation values, in the case that I have an annotation object (e.g. from `Class.getAnnotation`) and want to serialize it. This is independent of whether they are normally serialized in the course of serializing a class that has annotations.

Comment: @MichaelEkstrand - i understand that.  i was pointing out that annotation values wouldn't typically need to be serialized due the point that i mentioned.  the other answer definitely has the more pertinent fact, but this answer is not incorrect in and of itself.

Comment: It would be correct if you added "when serializing a class that has an annotation"